# Can't open large/huge file with vim, opens in "new file" mode

Tags: vim, ubuntu, large-files

I am trying to open a very large file (2Gb) with vim on ubuntu 10.04, but instead of opening the file, it opens in "new file" mode. Any clues as to what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks as always

Comment: how do you open it? `:e file_name`? Is there a space in the file name? Please provide details.

Comment: On a first guess, mis-typed filename?

Comment: I open it with vi <filename>. It's not mis-typed, since I press tab to autocomplete the name

Answer (score 1):

Start Vim with `vim -V9log` and check the `log` to see what happened.

Comment: ah, sorry, I didn't notice there's a "log" file. Here's the output: http://pastebin.com/Gp2ujfra